# Php POST not receiving any data

Tags: php, forms

I've just got into php recently, and now i am working on a login form which has a signup page and a signup script to do all the database and such. But my $_POST is  not working at all. I`ve tried searching online, confirm that my xampp/php/php.ini setting enable post process, and such. But all i get is nothing. To make the problem simpler i used a post tutorial code online

Posttest.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
<a href="welcome.php">Submit</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$disname="";
$disname = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';

echo "$disname is your username";
var_dump($_POST);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result is empty. Please help i`ve been working on this problem for few days.

Comment: <a href="welcome.php">Submit</a> is a link, and the FORM data does not get POSTed when you click on it. Replace it  with <input type="submit">

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I am self learning php, and this will be a valuable lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine but the submit href link, which you should replace with a Submit input type:

```
<a href="welcome.php">Submit</a>
```

to:

```
<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "a" tag for submit. "a" tag just direct to address. So you should use this:

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////welcome.php

<html>
<body>

<?php

$disname="";
$disname = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';

echo "$disname is your username";
var_dump($_POST);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In other words, you (correctly!) removed the `<a>`link and substituted an `<input type="submit">` button.  Q: Why didn't you explain that, instead of just posting code?  The explanation would help make your post much more useful to future readers.

Comment: Yes i know but most people just need what they want. Do not ask explanation. Therefor i things good to save somebody time unless somebody ask.